# Reverse triangle inequalities with three elements

Tags: inequality, triangles

Could you help me to show that
$$
|a-b-c|\geq |b|-|a|-|c|
$$
?

Comment: Any restrictions on what $a,b,c$ may be? Or can they be any real number?

Comment: any real number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|b| = |-b| \leq |a-b-c| + |c-a|$ by the triangle inequality, so $|a - b - c| \geq |b| - |c-a|$. Then you just need the triangle inequality again to get $|c-a| \leq |a| + |c|$, so $|b| - |c-a| \geq |b| - |a| - |c|$.